# Return and StopIteration in custom python generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, generator

Reading up on some of the new style points of view in Python and getting around to the shift from `StopIteration` to `return` in generators. My main question is exactly how this should work in a custom generator. I've got a class where I'm over-writing the `__next__` method directly as there's some logic I have to add in to track generation.

Below is pretty close to what I'm doing, has all of the critical elements. Note that I'm not actually just creating a generator that replicates a list, just making this a minimal example.

```
class Test():
    items = <list>

    def __init__(self):
        self.index = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index >= len(self.items):
            raise StopIteration
        value = self.items[self.index]
        self.index += 1
        return value

    def reset(self):
        self.index = 0
```

So in a case like this I'm iterating through a list until it's exhausted and then downstream calls will decide whether to reset the generator or to move on after it's exhausted. However, how do I enable something like this without using `StopIteration` since it's being deprecated? The standard advice of using `return` here to raise a `StopIteration` doesn't seem to apply and I'd really rather not change downstream code to check for a generator yielding `Nones`

So what am I supposed to do here? Are `StopIteration` exceptions still acceptable in `__next__`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StopIteration` is **not** being deprecated, you merely misunderstood something about what generators are. You don't actually have a generator, you have an *iterator*. Generators are simply functions that use `yield` to create an iterator.

You are creating your own base iterator implementation without using generators. And iterators raise `StopIterator` from `__next__` when they are done. Your code correctly does so here.

From the [*Generator Types* section](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types) of the Python datamodel documentation:

> Python’s [generator](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator)s provide a convenient way to implement the iterator protocol. If a container object’s [`__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method is implemented as a generator, it will automatically return an iterator object (technically, a generator object) supplying the [`__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) and [`__next__()`](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator.__next__) methods. More information about generators can be found in the documentation for the yield expression.

And from the same documentation, in the [*Iterator Types* section](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types):

> `iterator.__next__()`
>    Return the next item from the container. If there are no further items, raise the `StopIteration` exception.

There is a deprecation in place, but this only concerns using `StopIteration` in generator functions. See [PEP 479 - Change StopIteration handling inside generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/):

> This PEP proposes a change to generators: when `StopIteration` is raised inside a generator, it is replaced it with `RuntimeError`. (More precisely, this happens when the exception is about to bubble out of the generator's stack frame.) Because the change is backwards incompatible, the feature is initially introduced using a `__future__` statement.

Inside a generator, using `return` triggers the `StopIteration` exception. Raising `StopIteration` manually can actually create obscure bugs, because any consumer of the resulting iterator can't distinguish between *correct* use of the exception and *incorrect, accidental* `StopIteration` exceptions eminating from your generator. That makes such issues hard to debug, which is why their use inside a generator function is changing in a future Python version.

Side note: your implementation requires the [`iterator.__iter__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__iter__), which simply returns `self`.

Comment: I thought the distinction was just if I was lazily generating results? In this example obviously I'm not, but in my actual code `__next__` is lazily generating values. It does appear I've misunderstood exactly what was being deprecated (or rather, my linter did). But in this case it sounds like `StopIteration` is just fine to use?

Comment: @SlaterVictoroff: iterators are the things that lazily provide results. Generators are functions that create iterators by using `yield`, and by using `return` in a generator raising `StopIteration` is taken care of for you; when people talk about generators and `StopIteration` it is because you should not raise the exception manually. Your linter is confusing you, it should not warn about `StopIteration` when you are not using `yield`.

Comment: That makes tons of sense. Thanks for the clarification. I'll try to find some time to open a PR on the linter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a resettable wrapped generator, one possible option is to keep its data elsewhere:

```py
class Gen:
   def __init__(self):
      self.items = []
   def restart(self):
      for x in self.items:
         yield x

g = Gen()
for x in g.restart():
   pass
for x in g.restart():
   pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As I mentioned though, this isn't actually what I'm looking to do. I've got working code, really just a confusion about where throwing `StopIteration` is acceptable

Comment: I'd not call something `Gen` if it is not itself a generator. Only `Gen.restart()` is a generator here, that's not quite the same thing. And you didn't create a resettable iterator either, you implemented a *different* pattern, an *iterable*.  The usual way to create is with an `__iter__` method but no `__next__` method. Calling `__iter__` then creates the iterator object. Renaming `restart` to `__iter__` makes your example an iterable (so rename the class to `Iter` perhaps). Then simply use `i = Iter()` and two `for x in i:` loops.

Comment: And, actually, your code **doesn't work**, because not even `restart()` is a generator. Only the nested `ret_val()` function is, and you return that without calling it. As a result, the `for x in g.restart()` loop tries to iterate over a function object. That will raise a `TypeError` exception. There is no need, whatsoever, to use a nested function here.

Comment: I don’t get why you are returning a nested generator function still. There is absolutely no point here.